# Designing forms for printing in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, tools, print-design, forms

I have to make a lot of forms in InDesign.  Not interactive forms, just forms that need to be printed.  It's really a pain making all the checkboxes, radio buttons, lines and text fields and ensuring they all line up properly.  Is there a simple mechanism or toolset for creating standard forms?

Comment: Forms *are* a pain. It's a penance imposed on graphic designers for having too much fun on other jobs. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tables! Laying out in tables in InDesign is *awesome* for forms. You can stroke the bottom of a cell for the text field, make small uniform stroked cells for checkboxes, and use a character or paste in an image for a radio button. Unless you merge cells weirdly, everything has to line up.

Comment: AFAIK, you can make custom bullets. Make a checkbox bullet (etc) and then apply the proper paragraph style.

Comment: tables is definetlythe way to do it, google for a tutorial on how to use tables in InDesign